# CakePHP matching associated data, not all values return

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I've got Events and Distances, the models look like this:"

```
/* EventsTable.php */
class EventsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        ...
        $this->belongsToMany('Distances', [
            'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'distance_id',
            'joinTable' => 'distances_events',
            'dependent' => true
        ]);

/*DistancesTable.php*/
class DistancesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        ...
        $this->belongsToMany('Events', [
            'foreignKey' => 'distance_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'event_id',
            'joinTable' => 'distances_events'
        ]);
    }
```

With the following events (and distances)

- Event 1: 25km, 500km
- Event 2: 25km
- Event 3: 100km

I'm trying to select all Events that have at least one distances between the given min and max distances. So I use this code:

```
$mindistance = 50;
$maxdistance = 550;
$events = $this->Events
    ->find()
    ->contain(['Distances'])
    ->matching('Distances', function ($q) use ($maxdistance, $mindistance) {
      return $q->where(['Distances.title <=' => $maxdistance, 'Distances.title >=' => $mindistance]);
    });
```

Which returns me:

- Event 1: 500km
- Event 3: 100km

I am missing the 25km distance in the contained data.
How can I apply this filter, but with keeping all distances of the event?

Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
  Events.id AS Events__id, 
  Events.user_id AS Events__user_id, 
  Events.title AS Events__title, 
  Events.slug AS Events__slug, 
  Events.type AS Events__type, 
  Events.description AS Events__description, 
  Events.datetime AS Events__datetime, 
  Events.country AS Events__country, 
  Events.province AS Events__province, 
  Events.city AS Events__city, 
  Events.street AS Events__street, 
  Events.housenumber AS Events__housenumber, 
  Events.zipcode AS Events__zipcode, 
  Events.lat AS Events__lat, 
  Events.lon AS Events__lon, 
  Events.price AS Events__price, 
  Events.active AS Events__active, 
  Events.created AS Events__created, 
  Events.modified AS Events__modified, 
  DistancesEvents.distance_id AS DistancesEvents__distance_id, 
  DistancesEvents.event_id AS DistancesEvents__event_id, 
  Distances.id AS Distances__id, 
  Distances.title AS Distances__title, 
  Distances.created AS Distances__created, 
  Distances.modified AS Distances__modified 
FROM 
  events Events 
  INNER JOIN distances_events DistancesEvents ON Events.id = (DistancesEvents.event_id) 
  INNER JOIN distances Distances ON (
    Distances.title <= '550' 
    AND Distances.title >= '50' 
    AND Distances.id = (DistancesEvents.distance_id)
  )


SELECT 
  DistancesEvents.distance_id AS Distances_CJoin__distance_id, 
  DistancesEvents.event_id AS Distances_CJoin__event_id, 
  Distances.id AS Distances__id, 
  Distances.title AS Distances__title, 
  Distances.created AS Distances__created, 
  Distances.modified AS Distances__modified 
FROM 
  distances Distances 
  INNER JOIN distances_events DistancesEvents ON Distances.id = (DistancesEvents.distance_id) 
WHERE 
  DistancesEvents.event_id in (8, 10)
```

Comment: What's your exact CakePHP version? Is that really all the code for your query? How did you test that it's really the matching that affects your results? What does the generated SQL for fetching the associated records look like?

Comment: @ndm, I am using 3.8.10; I've added the generated SQL to the question.

Comment: Comparing numbers to apparent string columns is concerning, but it shouldn't affect the association query, or merging of its results. I can't reproduce your problem, using `3.8.10` matching and containing using your config works just fine over here.

Comment: @ndm, yeah it works. Found out that the tablefield `Distances.title` was a `varchar` instead of an `int`

Answer (score 0):

In EventsTable create two relationships to Distances, first for matching, second for all distances:

```
/* EventsTable.php */
class EventsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config): void
    {
        ...
        $this->belongsToMany('MatchedDistances', [
            'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'distance_id',
            'joinTable' => 'distances_events',
            'dependent' => true
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('Distances', [
            'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'distance_id',
            'joinTable' => 'distances_events',
            'dependent' => true
        ]);
```

Then:

```
$mindistance = 50;
$maxdistance = 550;
$events = $this->Events
    ->find()
    ->contain(['MatchedDistances'])
    ->contain(['Distances'])
    ->matching('MatchedDistances', function ($q) use ($maxdistance, $mindistance) {
      return $q->where(['MatchedDistances.title <=' => $maxdistance, 'MatchedDistances.title >=' => $mindistance]);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the afford. My code did work tho. It was a database table field (`Distances.title`) was a varchar instead of int